# Gaussian model fit

Tags: statistical-inference, surfaces, nonlinear-optimization, computational-geometry

Let's assume I have a set of 3D points that have been sampled on a surface of the form $(x,y,f(x,y))$ where $f$ is a 2D Gaussian function:
$$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_x \sigma_y} \exp{\left(-\frac1{2} \left(\frac{(x-\mu_x)^2}{\sigma_x^2}+\frac{(y-\mu_y)^2}{\sigma_y^2}\right)\right)},$$
or, in matricial form,
$$f({\bf x})=\tfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{|\Sigma|}} e^{\left(-\frac12 \left({\bf x} - {\bf \mu}\right)^T \Sigma^{-1} \left({\bf x} - {\bf \mu}\right)\right)},\quad{\bf x} = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix},\quad{\bf \mu} = \begin{bmatrix} \mu_x \\ \mu_y \end{bmatrix},\quad\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix} \sigma_x^2 && 0 \\ 0 && \sigma_y^2  \end{bmatrix}.$$
Here, $(\mu_x,\mu_y)$ indicates the center of the bell, and $\Sigma$ the way it spreads all over the plane. I'm thinking more from a geometric point of view, but, of course, those would be the mean and the covariance matrix (with uncorrelated variables) of a 2D normal distribution.

I know that, in case I wanted to recover those parameters from the set of points, I can use a nonlinear model fit. For instance, I've tried `NonlinearModelFit` in Mathematica and it works well.

[image: Gaussian]

But now, imagine that my set of points $\{(x_n,y_n,f(x_n,y_n))\}$ is rotated and/or translated to somewhere else in the 3D space. My question is the following one:

> Given a set of points $\{(x_k, y_k, z_k)\}_{k=1}^N$, what method can I use to guess the parameters for the rotation ($\theta_x,\theta_y,\theta_z$), the translation ($v_x,v_y,v_z$) and the Gaussian ($\sigma_x,\sigma_y$) such that
>   $$\begin{bmatrix} x_k \\ y_k \\ z_k \end{bmatrix} = R_{\theta_x,\theta_y,\theta_z}\begin{bmatrix} \tilde x_k \\ \tilde y_k \\ f_{\sigma_x,\sigma_y}(\tilde x_k,\tilde y_k) \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} v_x \\ v_y \\ v_z \end{bmatrix}$$
>   for some unknown $(\tilde x_k,\tilde y_k)\in\mathbb{R}^2$?

---

**EDIT:**

This is what I came up with so far. I have to solve the following optimization problem:
$$\min_{\begin{array}{c}\theta_x,\theta_y,\theta_z\\v_x,v_y,v_z\\\sigma_x,\sigma_y\end{array}} \sum_{k=1}^N \big(\tilde z_k - f_{\sigma_x,\sigma_y}(\tilde x_k,\tilde y_k)\big)^2$$
where
$$\begin{bmatrix} \tilde x_k \\ \tilde y_k \\ \tilde z_k \end{bmatrix} = R_{\theta_x,\theta_y,\theta_z}^{-1} \left(\begin{bmatrix} x_k \\ y_k \\ z_k \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} v_x \\ v_y \\ v_z \end{bmatrix} \right) $$
However, in this way I do not have the classical form of the residuals $r_k=z_k-g(x_k,y_k)$, where $g$ depends on the parameters. Can I go further or is that the final expression I should use?

Comment: Maybe this is not what you have in mind, but you can just invert the rotation/translation, then estimate your parameters and finally rotate/translate anyway you want.

Comment: @Marc The point is that I don't know any of those, neither. I have included that in the question, to make it clear, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You new model is still the Gaussian but applied to the $x,y,f$ coordinates *after* multiplication by the unknown rotation matrix and translation by the unknown vector, which adds $6$ parameters to your equations.

Anyway, this would form a degenerate problem as two translational degrees of freedom have the same effect as $\mu_x,\mu_y$, and one rotational degree of freedom has the effect of nonzero covariance.

So you can recast as the fitting of an $8$-parameter model including

- an arbitrary 3D rotation,
- an arbitrary 3D translation,
- a centered Gaussian for independent variables ($\Sigma$ diagonal).

Comment: Ok, so we can reduce from 11 to 8 parameters. In fact, they could be just 7, since rotation around the origin can be done using 2 parameters only, right? And what now? Classical nonlinear fit models are still not valid, since the points are not on the form $(x,y,f(x,y))$. Minimizing the mean square of the distances is neither clear to me, since I do not see a straightforward way of computing those distances. Any suggestion?

Comment: No, rotation takes $3$ parameters, and you can very well obtain an explicit formula in the form $z=f(x,y;\phi,\theta,\psi,t_x,t_y,t_z,\sigma_x,\sigma_y)$ by choosing the order of the transforms.

Comment: @AugSB: don't stay focus on that, there is a way...

Comment: No, my data is simply a set of points $\{(X_i,Y_i,Z_i)\}$; I don't have any information about how it was obtained (just that they belong to a Gaussian located somwhere in space). From that set of points I have to infere the rotation, the translation and the parameters of the Gaussian.

Comment: Ok, then after applying the rotation/translation, you have new points $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ for which you fit the Gaussian model, as I already explained.

Comment: @AugSB: grrrrr. The solution is in fromt of your eyes.

Comment: I have edited the question and added what I concluded so far. Could you please have a look at it and tell me whether I am in the good way? Thank you very much.